# How to filter objects inside arrays in DynamoDB

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm implementing query filters in my nodejs application.

In modeling, I have this schema:

```
 "clause": [
  {
   "description": "test1",
   "number": 200
  },
  {
   "description": "test2",
   "number": 201
  },
  {
   "description": "test3",
   "number": 202
  },
 ],
```

Basically I need to inform an array of objects to the dynamo and I need to know which record contains this information in which I searched

I've had success filtering just one object within the array, like this:

```
const params: QueryCommandInput = {
  TableName: config.CONTRACT_DB,
  KeyConditionExpression: 'pk = :i',
  FilterExpression: 'contains(#clause, :clause)',
  ExpressionAttributeNames: {
    '#clause': 'clause',
  },
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ':i': `user#${user.id}`,
    ':clause': {
      number: 200,
      description: 'test1',
    },
  },
};
```

But it is necessary for me to know the values ​​of number and description, I failed to get the result by informing only one of the properties.

And I have no idea how I would implement a solution where the user enters multiple clauses

Has anyone had success in querying objects inside arrays in dynamodb?, I didn't find anything relevant here.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what queries you need to support?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot search by description with the schema you designed. To search for a value, that value must be in the partition key (pk) or sort key (sk). You need to change the schema. I suggest splitting your array so that each item in the array is an item in the database. Then you can set the pk to a pointer to the parent object, and set sk to a number if you want to preserve the order of items in the array.

Next, create a GSI with the description as the pk, and the sk is your choice depending on your needs. Then you can search for an exact match with description by querying the GSI. If you want a partial search (begins_with), you can set the pk to a fixed value such as "clauseDescription", and the sk to description.